# Img overflowing into div trying to float next to text and clearfix is not working

Tags: html, css

Working on building a site for my portfolio and the `img` is overflowing into the next `div`. I tried using `clearfix` and it has not worked. I wanted the `img` next to the text in the "about me" section. I would like to know how I can avoid to this issue in the future and what steps do I need to take to accomplish what I would like. [What I have now](https://jsfiddle.net/8y14r68y/)

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title> Peter Santiago</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="inner">
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <h1>I'm
    <br>
    Peter Santiago </h1>
  <span>Freelance Creative</span>
</div>
</header>
<div class="intro">
    <h2>About Me </h2>
    <div class="clearfix">
    <img class="img-circle" src='https://i.imgur.com/YzoIKdk.jpg'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      In quibus doctissimi illi veteres inesse quiddam caeleste et divinum putaverunt.
      Sed haec quidem liberius ab eo dicuntur et saepius. Si de re disceptari oportet,
      nulla mihi tecum, Cato, potest esse dissensio. </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skills">
    <h2>My Skills </h2>
</body>
</html>

/* About me-----------------*/
.intro{
  background:white;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 300px;
}

.intro h2 {
color:#5D667C ;
font-family:"Open Sans";
font-weight:800;
font-size: 4em;
text-align: center;

}
.img-circle {
float:left;
}

.intro p {
  text-align:justify;

}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Skills---------------*/
.skills {
  background-color:#5D667C ;
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
}

.skills h2 {
  color:white ;
  font-family:"Open Sans";
  font-weight:800;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;

}
```

What results I would like [image]

Comment: Your code is somewhat correct, its just that your image isn't properly cropped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "float: left" css property in the image css stylesheet.I hope my answer help you..

and make a external css file and include into the main page in order to find errors more easily among modules of the Portfolio Site.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `.intro` . This will make sure that the container completely wraps around any floated element in it.